# urllib throws an exception for non 200 status codes, where as urllib3 and requests gives the proper response

Tags: python, rest, python-requests, urllib, urllib3

In the below code example `xyz.com/apicall` rest api call gives below response incase of non 200 Status code error .

```
{"error":"<Error Name>","errorMessage":"<Error Description>","host":null}
```

```
import json
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
from urllib import request
import urllib3


url = 'xyz.com/apicall'
payload = json.dumps({
  "key1": "value1",
}).encode('utf-8')

print ("#######Request By Requests Module###########")

headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json',}
response= requests.post(url,headers=headers, data=payload)
print('Response Code: {}'.format(response.status_code))
print('Response Body: {}'.format(response.text))

print ("#######Request By urllib###########")
req = request.Request(url)  # this will make the method "POST"
req.add_header("Content-Type", "application/json")
try:
  response_url = request.urlopen(req, data=payload)
  print(response_url.read())
except:
  print("Error Occured in URLLIB")


print ("#######Request By urllib3###########")

http = urllib3.PoolManager()
r = http.request('POST', url, headers=headers, body=payload)
resp_body = r.data.decode('utf-8')
resp_dict = json.loads(r.data.decode('utf-8'))
print('Response Code: {}'.format(r.status))
print('Response Body: {}'.format(resp_body))
print ("End")
```

When I run the above code I get o/p like this.

```
#######Request By Requests Module###########
Response Code: 400
Response Body: {"error":"<Error Name>","errorMessage":"<Error Description>","host":null}
#######Request By urllib###########
Error Occured in URLLIB
#######Request By urllib3###########
Response Code: 400
Response Body: {"error":"<Error Name>","errorMessage":"<Error Description>","host":null}
End
```

So in case of **urllib** I get an exception where as in urllib3 and Requests I get the actual HTTP Response. How can I replicate the same in urllib.